# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method group(Ljava/lang/String;) JDBC related

Tags: java, android, jdbc

I am actually working on databases in an android app (using android studio). And I am stuck to this error saying:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method group(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; in class Ljava/util/regex/Matcher; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.util.regex.Matcher' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
```

[Full error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHoZP.png)

So, the problem is, my code does compile, I do have everything that compiles but when I execute this part it shuts off my application. Since DB in java/android studio is new to me I'll take every tips you have.

And to be honest I do not understand what I should do ...

Here's the class i use and call in my code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MySQLConnector {
    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";
    private static final String user = "root";
    private static final String password = "password";

    private  Connection con;
    private  Statement stmt;
    private  ResultSet rs;

    public MySQLConnector() throws SQLException {
        try { 
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            stmt = con.createStatement();

        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    void sendUpdate(String req) throws SQLException {
        stmt.executeUpdate(req);
        System.out.println("Command executed");

    }
    public void sendRequest(String req) throws SQLException {
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(req);
        System.out.println("Command executed");

    }
}
```

And here's a use example in my code:

```
public class Check extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button finApp ;
    private Intent intent;
    private String sessionID;
    private MySQLConnector connector;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_check);
        intent = getIntent();
        sessionID = intent.getStringExtra("SessionID");
        System.out.println("oncreatebutton");
        finApp=findViewById(R.id.button);
        try {
            connector = new MySQLConnector();
            connector.sendRequest("Select * from users");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finApp.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            try {
                connector.sendUpdate("INSERT INTO users (first_name,last_name," +
                        "date_created,is_admin,num_points) VALUES('name','lastname',now(),0,6)");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("test");

            System.out.println("Session id is :" + sessionID);
            finish();
        });
    }
}
```

```
connector = new MySQLConnector();
connector.sendRequest("Select * from users");
```

are the ones that fail

Thanks a lot for anyone that tries to help.

Comment: Never heard of mysql in android. I guess you probably need to use SQLite or use a remote connection.

Comment: It did work once or twice and I was able to read information from my database. Do you think working with SQLite will work easier @RicardoA.?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do. If you only need to work with the information in your phone it is better to use SQLite, otherwise if that code worked you're probably in the right path.

Comment: I should be able to have a shared database between 1 sender and X receiver. and send should be able to fetch datas entries that "receiver" sent in this same database. Plus, your comment made me think about how do i fetch a local DB with multiples devices. It might be the issue.

Comment: Seems you're working with a specific SDK (or lib). You should tell that in the question, so it will be easier for others to identify the problem.

Comment: The libs I may be using are JDBC (to use mysql) and an app "package"(Copsonic)

Comment: You should not use JDBC drivers from Android. You shouldn't connect directly to remote databases from a mobile device. It has bad performance and is pretty insecure compared to using a REST api to mediate between your application and database. In addition, recent JDBC drivers are likely to use newer Java features that aren't available in Android. For example, the driver is calling `Matcher.group(String)` introduced in Java 7, which - given the NoSuchMethodError -  doesn't seem to exist in the Android API level you're using.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the usefull informations, I did not knew that JDBC may not be the best way to manage databases in Android. I'll check what you've recommended. Thanks !